# Open plain text file in Excel from HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'd like to create an HTML page with links to various documents that open in Excel. The problem is that the documents are plain text files. I don't want them to open in Notepad, but rather Excel. Is there a way to do this from within an HTML document? (Using JavaScript is fine.)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user doesn't have excel installed?  What if they use Libre Office or some other spreadsheet program?  Could you have them saved as .csv instead?

Comment: This is an in-house tool that won't see the light of day outside our local developer machines, so this is irrelevant for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a cross-browser compatible version way to do it.  In fact, I think you can only do this if you are using Internet Explorer, so before you do it consider those on Mac and Linux that cannot have the latest version of IE or thoughs on Windows who do not want to use IE.  But, using Javascript and ActiveX objects there is [this script](http://www.oshyn.com/_blog/Software_Development/post/10_Lines_or_Less_-_Export_HTML_Table_to_Excel/) that can change an HTML table into an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by the end user's operating system and how it reads mime-types by default. It's not something you can handle in your code.